# Is JsonRequest<String> a good idea?

Tags: android, json, api, web-services, android-volley

I'm currently using volley on a project and, I want to send a **JSON body** and retrieve a **String as response**.

For this, I've created a class with a JsonRequest as a parent.

It looks like this:

```
public class JAStringRequest extends JsonRequest<String> {
    private String token;
    private Response.Listener<String> listener;
    @Nullable
    private Response.ErrorListener errorListener;

    public JAStringRequest(String token, int method, String url, @Nullable String requestBody, Response.Listener<String> listener, @Nullable Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, requestBody, listener, errorListener);
        this.token = token;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.errorListener = errorListener;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        try {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            String auth = "Bearer " + token;
            headers.put("Authorization", auth);
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return headers;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Authentication Failure");
        }
        return super.getHeaders();
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        Log.d(TAG, "parseNetworkResponse " + response.statusCode);
        try {
            String jsonString =
                    new String(
                            response.data,
                            HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, PROTOCOL_CHARSET));
            return Response.success(
                    jsonString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(String response) {
        super.deliverResponse(response);
        Log.d(TAG, "deliverResponse: " + response);
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
        Log.d(TAG, "parseNetworkError");
        if (volleyError.networkResponse != null
                && volleyError.networkResponse.data != null) {
            volleyError = new VolleyError(new String(
                    volleyError.networkResponse.data));
            return volleyError;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I never retrieve the response out of the *parseNetworkResponse*. (the log "parseNetworkResponse 200")

```
JAStringRequest request = new JAStringRequest(jwtToken, Request.Method.POST, url.toString(), array.toString(),
                                    response -> {
                                        if (response.equals("200")) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "DBrequest result: " + key + " => " + response);
                                        } else {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "DBrequest error: " + key + " => " + response);
                                        }
                                        isRequestEnded.set(true);
                                    },
                                    error -> {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "DBrequest Error message: " + key + " => " + error.getMessage());
                                    });
                            request.setTag(key);
                            queue.add(request);
```

Here the listener is never triggered, the log doesn't show.

Any clue ?

Thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by adding a boolean in my custom JsonRequest class. This boolean is initialized false and then passed to true in the parseNetworkResponse.
We go out of the while when this Boolean is true.

```
public class JAStringRequest extends JsonRequest<String> {
    ...
    private boolean isResponse = false;

    ...

    @Override
    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        Log.d(TAG, "parseNetworkResponse");
        isResponse = true;
    ...
    }

    ...

    public boolean isResponse() {
        return isResponse;
    }
}
```

```
queue.add(request);
while (!request.isResponse()) {
}
```

It's the only way i found to make it work, else what the response never go through to the response.listener .

*PS: The while is there to do the requests as LIFO's in a for loop.*